# Trigger old and new for update operation

Tags: trigger, update

I have pretty complicated situation here!

I have a field on `User` named `Credit__c` and another field on `Time_Off__c`  named `Days__c`.

When I add a `Time_Off__c` with a number of days  => `Credit__c` -= `Days__c` (we subtract number of days from the credit) BUT I need to update the `Days__c` field so the new `Credit__c` will be update as well.

My solution is:

`Credit__c` new =  ABS(`Days__c` old - `Days__c` new) + `Credit__c` old

(p.s. ABS the absolute value)

I need to manipulate my trigger with old and new records.

Is this possible?

Comment: Speaking from experience, it would be good to get started on something and ask direct questions. The guys here are really good and helpful but they won't write the code for you.

Comment: What is the relationship between the two objects? On which object your are trying to write the trigger?

Comment: Yeah I know Eric!!! m working on the code ! but getting confused with old and new record! so if you have any example thank you in advance
REGARDS

Comment: Please show us what you have.

Comment: The user with logged session has the right to create his own time_Off__c. I'm trying to update a custom field on User object

Comment: Updating other object's fields are ok with triggers, but to do so well need a relation between them(specially in a multitenant environment like salesforce ). @Keith C has given a solution assuming a relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is something of a guess because you have not responded to highfive's comment and your question is not entirely clear. This code assumes that there is a lookup relationship between `Time_Off__c` and `User` via an id field called `User__c`.

It illustrates that the [Trigger context variable](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) holds references to the values of the objects before they were changed (the old fields) and after they have been changed (the new fields) and this allows you to look at the difference between old and new values:

```
trigger TimeOffTrigger on Time_Off__c (before update) {

    // Get the current Credit values
    Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Time_Off__c newTimeOff : Trigger.new) {
        userIds.add(newTimeOff.User__c);
    }
    Map<Id, User> users = new Map<Id, User>([
            select Id, Credit__c
            from User
            where Id in :userIds;
            ]);

    // Update Credit values with the changed days
    for (Time_Off__c newTimeOff : Trigger.new) {
        Time_Off__c oldTimeOff = Trigger.oldMap.get(newTimeOff.Id);
        User u = users.get(newTimeOff.User__c);
        u.Credit__c += (oldTimeOff.Days__c - newTimeOff.Days__c);
    }
    update users.value();
}
```

This is only handling the update case, so you may also need to code for the insert case and perhaps the delete case too. And if fields allow nulls you will need more defensive code.

If none of this makes any sense, I recommend you Google and watch some YouTube presentations and generally read more on the subject. It is particularly important to get comfortable with using sets and maps.

**PS**

The recent comments on the question suggest that this is what is required (though at first sight it looks quite unusual):

```
trigger TimeOffTrigger on Time_Off__c (before update) {
    User u = [
            select Id, Credit__c
            from User
            where Id in :UserInfo.getUserId()
            ];
    for (Time_Off__c newTimeOff : Trigger.new) {
        Time_Off__c oldTimeOff = Trigger.oldMap.get(newTimeOff.Id);
        u.Credit__c += (oldTimeOff.Days__c - newTimeOff.Days__c);
    }
    update u;
}
```

Comment: I have a problem when I put my code in method on apex class and call it with after update trigger. Can't figure out why! here is the error : 


Save error: Illegal assignment from SObject to SOBJECT:Time_Off__c 

in this line of code :

Time_Off__c oldTimeOff= Trigger.oldMap.get(newTimeOff.Id);

Comment: @KawtarBRAZI I think the problem is that inside the trigger the type can be inferred, but outside it can't. If moving code outside the trigger, best to pass Trigger.oldMap and any other Trigger values you need as method parameters rather than grabbing them from the Trigger global. Then as well as being clearer code, the type is tied down both in the trigger and in the class i.e. "methodName(Map<Id, Time_Off__c> oldMap, Map<Id, Time_Off__c> newMap)" and newMap.values() can be used in place of Trigger.new.